# Fgets Only Reading 2 Lines of a File

Tags: c, csv, file-io, scanf

I'm trying to read watercraft info from lines of a comma delimited text file into a linked list. I read each line using fgets and then parse the data into the linked list node using sscanf. So far it only reads 2 lines and then repeats the data from the second line over and over for the rest of the lines when printing.

The function below is called in a while loop until it reaches the end of the file. This function is what gets the values and returns a node to be put in a linked list. The function is called the correct number of times until it reaches the end of the file but for some reason it is only capturing the first 2 items I need.

```
// Create watercrafts from the info in file
watercraft_t *new_waterCraft( FILE *inFile )
{
    watercraft_t *newNode;

    newNode = (watercraft_t*)malloc(sizeof(watercraft_t));

    int length = 0;
    int ch;
    long offset= ftell(inFile);

    // Calculate length of next line
    while((ch = fgetc(inFile)) != '\n' && ch != EOF)
        length++;
        
    // Go back to beginning of line
    fseek(inFile, offset, SEEK_SET);

    
    // Allocate space for line plus BOTH \n AND \0
    char *buffer = malloc(length+2);

    // Read the line
    fgets(buffer, length+2, inFile);

    sscanf(buffer, "%14[^,], %19[^,], %29[^,], %d , %14[^,], %d, %24[^,], %d, %lf, %lf, %lf, %lf, %lf, %lf, %lf, %lf, %lf", newNode->type, newNode->make, newNode->model, &(newNode->propulsion), newNode->engine, &(newNode->hp), newNode->color, &(newNode->length), &(newNode->base_price), &(newNode->total_price), &(newNode->extras.bimini), &(newNode->extras.towbar), &(newNode->extras.stereo), &(newNode->extras.table), &(newNode->extras.gps), &(newNode->extras.anchor), &(newNode->extras.paddles));

    // Cleanup
    free(buffer);

    return newNode;
}
```

As you can tell there is a lot of data that I am capturing but for testing I have only been printing the boat type.

Print Function:

```
// Prints out whole list
void printList ( list_t *list )
{
    watercraft_t *currentCraft = list->head;

    int i = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < list->size; i++)
    {
        printf("%d. %s\n",i + 1, currentCraft->type);

        currentCraft = list->head->next;
    }
}
```

Here is the input file I'm using (I can't make changes to this):

```
pontoon,Crest,Carribean RS 230 SLC,1,Suzuki,115,Blue,26,134595.00,135945.00,1,200,0,250,450,450,0
fishing,Key West,239 FS,1,Mercury,250,Orange,24,86430.00,87630.00,0,0,250,200,500,250,0
sport boat,Tahoe,T16,1,Yamaha,300,Yellow,22,26895.00,27745.00,0,250,0,0,350,250,0
pontoon,Bennington,24 Slx,1,Mercury,140,Brown,24,83299.00,84049.00,1,250,0,200,0,300,0
kayak,Wilderness Systems,Tarpon 120 SOT,0,None,0,Red/Orange/Yellow,12,999.00,1149.00,0,0,0,0,0,0,150
pontoon,Suntracker,Bass Buggy 16 XL,1,Suzuki,115,Silver,22,13990.00,14990.00,1,200,0,250,300,250,0
pontoon,Crest,Classic LX 220 SLC,1,Mercury,115,Green,24,45599.00,47149.00,1,250,350,200,450,300,0
fishing,Phoenix,Bass Boat 920 Elite,2,Chevrolet,300,Orange,28,46995.00,48195.00,0,0,250,300,400,250,0
kayak,Eddyline,Rio,0,None,0,Green Apple,12,1429.00,1714.00,0,0,0,0,0,0,285
canoe,Old Town,Penobscot 164 ,0,None,0,Green,16,1299.95,1524.90,0,0,0,0,0,0,224.95
canoe,Mad River,Adventure 16,0,None,0,Red,16,899.00,1058.95,0,0,0,0,0,0,159.95
pontoon,Crest,Classic LX 200 L,1,Yamaha,150,Black,22,31816.00,33016.00,1,200,0,250,450,300,0
sport boat,Chaparral,297 Surf SSX,2,Chevrolet,300,Purple,24,220079.00,221279.00,0,250,350,0,400,200,0
fishing,Avenger,AV24,1,Yamaha,115,Gray,28,89995.00,90795.00,0,0,250,0,350,200,0
sport boat,Sea Ray,SDX 270,2,Chevrolet,300,Blue,28,185113.00,186213.00,0,200,300,0,350,250,0
fishing,Nitro,Z18 Pro,1,Suzuki,140,Black,30,35585.00,36235.00,0,0,0,0,400,250,0
pontoon,Bennington,25 Qxfb,1,Mercury,115,White,22,167000.00,168250.00,1,250,0,250,450,300,0
pontoon,Bentley,200 Cruise,1,Mercury,90,Silver,20,36995.00,37795.00,1,200,350,250,0,0,0
```

And lastly here is my output that I am getting right now:

```
1. pontoon
2. fishing
3. fishing
4. fishing
5. fishing
6. fishing
7. fishing
8. fishing
9. fishing
10. fishing
11. fishing
12. fishing
13. fishing
14. fishing
15. fishing
16. fishing
17. fishing
18. fishing
```

So, how do I fix it so that it reads the correct boat types from the input file instead of only the first 2 lines?

Comment: What is `watercraft_t`? Are the strings in it pointers or arrays? And how do you use the functions you show? Can you please try to create a [mcve] to show us?

Comment: You seem to have 18 lines in the input file, and 18 lines in the output. That would seem to indicate that the file is read and the list size set correctly. But we don't know how the list is built, you're not showing that. In `printList`, you're setting `currentCraft = list->head->next`, and if `list->head` is the first element, then that one's probably the second. Which is what you're printing.

Comment: If @ilkkachu is correct about printing of the list, then that could have been solved within a minute using a *debugger*. So the lesson of today is: Learn how to use a debugger! It's really a crucial tool for programmers and mandatory knowledge.

Comment: Hmm, you do not test the return value of `sscanf`. If a field is greater than expected, you will not find the comma after it and neither this value nor the following ones will be set. The `scanf` family functions are called a *poor man's parser* for a reason...

Comment: @SergeBallesta, hmm, did I read you wrong, in something like `sscanf("foobardoo, 123", "%5[^,], %d", str, &i)`, surely the string conversion `%5[^,]` to `str` should be filled? The comma after it isn't part of the conversion specifier. But yes, they should also check the return value of `sscanf()`, esp. since the structure is allocated with `malloc()` and not `calloc()`, so could be initially filled with garbage.

Comment: @ilkkachu: you are right. Only the following values will not be filled...

Comment: regarding; long offset= ftell(inFile);      // Calculate length of next line     while((ch = fgetc(inFile)) != '\n' && ch != EOF)         length++;              // Go back to beginning of line     fseek(inFile, offset, SEEK_SET); This can be simplified to 'char buffer = malloc(1024);'   fgets( inFile, buffer, 1024 ); however, the problem is in the code where the linked list is created/updated

Comment: regarding: `int i = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < list->size; i++)
    {
        printf("%d. %s\n",i + 1, currentCraft->type);

        currentCraft = list->head->next;
    }`  
suggest: `for( int i = 0; currentCraft != NULL; i++ ) {  printf("%d. %s\n", i + 1, currentCraft->type ); currentCraft = currentCraft->next; }`

Comment: there is no need to `malloc()` and `free()` `buffer`   Rather just use:  `char bufferf[1024];`  as that will disappear every time it goes 'out of scope